# How to use an array of values when using select on a csv in Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, select

PowerShell I have an array of columns

```
$columns = @("column1", "column2", "column3")
```

I want to select only the $columns from a set of data like so:

```
$data | select column1, column2, column3 | Export-Csv -Path "data.csv"
```

Since I don't know the exact names of the columns I am trying to pull, (`$columns` value will be dependent on backend response) I can't hard code those column names in.

When i try:

```
$data | select $columns | Export-Csv -Path "data.csv"
```

It reads the columns as "column1" instead of column1, and cannot find a column of that name.

If I define `$columns = @(column1, column2, column3)`

it throws as syntax error.

Comment: You can reference the columns via their position rather than name using `$columns[0]` `$columns[1]` and `$columns[2]`

Comment: Your first array definition is correct, and it wouldn't produce the symptom you describe.

Comment: ```$columns = @("column1", "column2", "column3"); @( [pscustomobject] @{ "column1"="c1"; "column2"="c2"; "column3"="c3" }) | select-object $columns``` appears to work fine here - can you show a single cut&pastable code sample that demonstrates the problem (and please test it locally first to confirm)

Comment: Can you describe what exactly is in `$data` ? An aray of PSObjects? a Hashtable or ??

Comment: @mklement0 it is indeed producing the symptom im describing, hence the question

Comment: @Theo it is an import of a csv

Comment: @mclayton's example demonstrates that the code you're showing works as expected.  If it doesn't, the implication is that the `select` alias has been redefined to refer to something other than `Select-Object` or that the property names of the objects in `$data` aren't what you expect. Without a [mcve] it is unlikely that someone will be able to help you.